# cant upload data from excel into database using php

Tags: php

I cant upload data from excel into database using php and mysql.My code is given below.

Using these code added some unwanted data. Anyone can give me solution for these issue?

HTML:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputFile">File Upload</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" size="150">
        <p class="help-block">Only Excel/CSV File Import.</p>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="Import" value="Import">Upload</button>
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST["Import"]))
    {
        $host='localhost'; // Host Name.
        $db_user= 'root'; //User Name
        $db_password= '';
        $db= 'excel'; // Database Name.
        $conn=@mysql_connect($host,$db_user,$db_password) or die (mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db($db) or die (mysql_error());
        echo $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
        if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
        {
            $file = fopen($filename, "r");
            $count = 0;   
            //$sql_data = "SELECT * FROM prod_list_1 ";
            while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
            {
                /*print_r($emapData);
                exit();*/
                $count++;  
                if($count>1)
                {
                   echo $in="insert into first (name, email) values('$emapData[0]','$emapData[1]')";
                   $insertTable= mysql_query($in);
                }   

            }
            fclose($file);
            echo 'CSV File has been successfully Imported';
            header('Location: index.php');
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Invalid File:Please Upload CSV File';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Your getting any errors?

Comment: 'ý '    these data is added into database,this is not my excel data

Comment: Are you trying to import a `CSV`-file? If you are using `XLS` or `XLSX`, please convert them in Excel to `CSV` prior to invoking the script...

Comment: shows these error Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\exce\first.php on line 23....line 23 is   echo $in="insert into first (name, email) values('$emapData[0]','$emapData[1]')";

Comment: i am trying for xls file

Comment: give name to your form

Comment: @shkk doing xls might cause unwanted errors convert it to CSV and try again.

Comment: Converted xls to csv,it is working fine